# How to create a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, fork

I am a research student working on an experiment involving Linux, and for it I need to create processes. I know how to create them with the `fork()` system call, but I was wondering if there was an alternate way to make them, without cloning the process it's called from?

Answer (score 2):

When creating a new process, the parent process would have to be responsible for any resources consumed by the new process-to-be until it actually becomes a stand-alone process. Dealing with that would probably be more complex than with the `fork()` behavior, but as @炸鱼薯条德里克 said in the comments, there is a `clone()` system call that allows you to have more control to the specifics of the thread/process creation.

The `fork()` system call actually avoids copying memory as much as possible, through the use of copy-on-write memory management. When `fork()` is executed, both the new process and its parent will be initially accessing the same memory (only the page tables of the parent process are actually copied initially), but that memory is marked as Copy-on-Write for the processor's memory management unit. If the child process immediately uses `execve()` to load a new program, the child gets its own memory allocations as part of the `execve()` and the parent's Copy-on-Write restriction is removed: the optimization works as intended.

But if either the parent or the child process modifies any of the temporarily-shared memory pages before the child executes `execve()`, then the Copy-on-Write bit causes a page fault before the write actually proceeds, the kernel makes a second copy of the memory page that is going to be modified, and then both the parent and the child process get their own, regular, writeable copies of that memory page with the expected contents. So if a process uses `fork()` without `execve()`, the actual copying happens later, with per-memory-page granularity, according to what pages are actually being written.

The `vfork()` system call makes this optimization explicit: the parent process/thread is suspended when `vfork()` is executed, until the child process calls either `execve()` or `_exit()`. Before the `vfork()`ed child process does an `execve()`, it must restrict itself to not doing certain things. This minimizes the chance that any memory copying is needed.

As far as I know, besides `fork()`, `vfork()` and `clone()` system calls, there is no other way to create new processes from within userspace. If you're within kernel code, there may be different options available, depending on exactly what part of the kernel you're in.